# console.log(person.sayName()); gives me undefined

Tags: javascript

Why is there undefined in my console?

```js
var person = {
  name: "Subash",
  sayName: function() {
    console.log('Hi, ' + this.name);
  }
}
console.log(person.sayName());
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US? Shouting is rude. It won't help you get an answer any faster. Instead, explain the problem you're having more clearly than WHAT'S WRONG WITH MY CODE, and do it in your question. See [ask]. Better yet, take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to learn how to conduct yourself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person.sayName()` doesn't return anything and so `undefined`.

```js
var person = {
  name: "Subash",
  sayName: function () {
    console.log('Hi, ' + this.name);
    return 'Hi, ' + this.name;
  }
}

console.log(person.sayName());
```

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your undefined is because of the line

> console.log(person.sayName());

Since person.sayName() returns nothing, that line is logging as undefined

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
var person = {
    name: "Subash",
    sayName: function() {
        console.log('Hi, ' + this.name);
    }
}
person.sayName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to see 2 `undefined`s in your console: both are the result of evaluating the two expressions, first being the declaration of `person` and the second being the `console.log()`.